# How to get the TipTap Editor to recognize updated external state values

Tags: reactjs, tiptap

This is likely an issue with my inexperience using React generally, but I'd still greatly appreciate any insights.

I've added a commenting plugin to the TipTap editor.

1. When I create a new comment, it creates a DB record for the comment and I store that new comment in a state value (React) which is an array of all comments.
2. Then I return the ID which I use in a setComment (Mark) command that wraps the selection in a span with a `commentId` on the `data-comment` attribute.
3. When I click on that span, I can get the ID value, but the editor `selectionUpdate` function doesn't see the updated value. The page can access it fine, but that function can't see it until the page is reloaded.

**How do I convince the editor to recognize the updated value in that function?**

A minimal app demo can be found here:

[image: Edit tiptap-react (forked)]

Once you make a comment, and click on it, you'll see that it doesn't find the newly added comment. That's what I'm try to fix. It should be able to find it.

I understanding the the useEffect isn't being updated because the dependency array does not include `chapterComments` - but if I add it, then `selectionUpdate` runs multiple times and only the last one is accurate. I don't know how to appropriate destroy or update the editor instance - though I assume that's what I need to do.

Answer (score 3):

The TipTap editor hook, `const editor = useEditor`, has it's own dependency array. Instead of trying to use `useEffect` with an `editor` dependency, just use the built in one for any values the editor needs to keep track of.

/facepalm

Comment: Thank you Jed, took me a couple of days to find your answer which worked perfectly. I can't seem to find this in the documentation, could you please post a reference to help prevent future headaches?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use a [command](https://tiptap.dev/api/commands#content) from Tiptap editor.
I hope this solution help you.

```js
const ArticleContent = ({ content }) => {
  const extensions = useExtensions();

  const editor = useEditor({
    extensions,
    content,
    editable: false,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    editor?.commands.setContent(content);
  }, [content, editor]);

  return <StyledEditorContent editor={editor} />;
};
```